# How would I distribute objects on a cloth simulated mesh and have them keep their distributed positions while not spawning in/out?

Tags: geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation

I have simulated a mesh inflating and deflating using a cloth simulation. Then, I added a geometry node setup to distribute objects on that mesh. The problem I keep running into is that when the cloth is simulated, some objects spawn in and out, or change position. I think this is because the distance between objects changes from the cloth animation and therefore objects that are too close get de-spawned. Ideally, I want to keep the initial distance between the distributed objects, but have them stay in their positions along the cloth simulated mesh without spawning in or not. For my situation, some intersecting is fine; I am mostly worried about objects popping in and out. I have attached an image of my node setup below.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Duplicate the cloth object and remove the Geometry Nodes modifier
2. Remove the Cloth modifier from the original object
3. Add a Surface Deform modifer after the geometry nodes
4. Target the cloth object with the Surface Deform modifer on the geo nodes object and bind

[image: Surf Def Nodes]

Comment: thank you so much! This solved my problem. I ran into another issue which was that my mesh was too complex and the modifier kept saying "contains invalid polygons"; however, that is a different issue. So, this solution did totally work on a reduced version of my mesh. Thank you again :)

Comment: @badatblender No problem! Depending on your mesh you may get better results using the Mesh Deform modifier instead.